# Question about Affine Connection

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, affine-geometry, information-geometry

[image]

In the book "Information geometry by Shun-Ichi Amari" he defines the affine connection the following way as you can see in the image. I want to know how we got the relation $(1.27)$.Is there any proof of this or anything? Please suggest.

Comment: This discussion is very heuristic and not totally rigorous

Comment: can you give an example to construct such a map.That will help to visualize.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection